# mapping data from more than one table

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

is there any way to map data from two tables using Mapper.CreateMap()?
eg:- i have two tables document and documentdetails.i want to get data from both tables and map them into one model which is documentmodel.how can i do this using the above method in .net?
thanx:)

Comment: How are these tables loaded into .NET -- nHibernate?  Entity Framework? ADO.NET datasets?  Knowing where the tables exist in memory will help answer the question.

Comment: So I assume you have a Document class that contains a DocumentDetails reference?  If so, then you really only have one class to map since the DocumentDetails has a reference to the details.

Comment: Could you post some code? The class definition for Document and DocumentDetails could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use resolver in Automapper's ResolveUsing(). e.g:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap()
     .ForMember(x=>x.DocumentDetails, opt=>opt.ResolveUsing<DocumentDetailsResolver>()
        .FromMember(src=>src.Document.DocumentId);
```

Then in your DocumentDetailsResolver class:

```
    public class DocumentDetailsResolver: ValueResolver<int, List<DocumentDetails>{
       protected override List<DocumentDetails> ResolveCore(int source)
       {
          // Put your logic to get the list of document details, source is the ID of the document
         // Return the list
       }
    }
```